# hide component, then show it, values are not saved

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2.0 web app with ajaxified tabs.

To switch tabs I show one and hide the others (Either with a conditional `render="#{x==y}"` or with with `display:none/block` through conditional `styleClass``ing.

In either case I get the tabs to show or hide correctly.

The problem is that the values entered in the input boxes are not retained throw a hide/show of a tab (In other words, if you enter some values in tab 1, go to tab 2 and back to tab 1, the values are not retained).

I use this `<f:ajax>` tag on tab selection (ignited by a hash change event)

```
<h:form id="processFragment" prependId="false" class="hide">
    <h:inputText id="fragment" value="#{fbean.fragment}">
        <f:ajax event="change" execute="contentSection" listener="#{fbean.processFragment}"
            render="contentSection" />
    </h:inputText>
</h:form>
<div>
    <h:form id="contentSection">
        <ui:insert name="content" />
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Thanks!

The code the display the tab bar and the tab contents:

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <f:view>
        <h:panelGroup styleClass="navBar">
            <ul>
                <ui:repeat value="#{hello.tabList}" var="tab">
                    <li onclick="window.location='\##{tab.tabHash}'"><h:panelGroup
                            styleClass="#{hello.chose == tab.tabHash?'activeTab':''}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{tab.tabName}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </li>
                </ui:repeat>
            </ul>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="contentPanels" styleClass="tabContentBar">
            <c:forEach items="#{hello.tabList}" var="tab">
                <h:panelGroup rendered="#{hello.chose == tab.tabHash}">
                    <!-- <h:panelGroup styleClass="#{hello.chose == tab.tabHash?'shownTabContents':'hiddenTabContents'}">  -->
                    <ui:include src="#{tab.tabFile}" />
                </h:panelGroup>
            </c:forEach>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:view>
</ui:define>
```

Finally, the contents of the specific tab:

```
<h:outputText value="TESTING 1" />
<h:panelGroup styleClass="formField">
    <h:outputText value="Enter Value:" />
    <h:inputText value="#{general.name}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

**UPDATE**
Just noticed that even if I don't hide the tabs and press a button, the value is reset. Investigating...

Comment: can you show the tab part of your xhtml with the hide/show events?

Comment: @Dave - Added code. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values will only be retained if you use a view scoped bean and the desired form is been submitted to the server side during (or right before) tab navigation.

As an alternative, you could render all tabs at once and use only JS/CSS to show/hide tab contents. CSS-hidden inputs will still be submitted to the server side.

Comment: Tnx. Does Hiding in CSS means assigning a class with `display:none`?

Comment: Yes. And then toggle with JS only.

Comment: is the commented-out line `<h:panelGroup styleClass="#{hello.chose == tab.tabHash?'shownTabContents':'hiddenTabContents'}">` not JS only? (Because that doesn't work)

Comment: Just noticed that even if I don't hide the tabs and press a button, the value is reset. Investigating...

Comment: @Ben: that's JSF and EL. With JS I mean JavaScript. The code which goes in `<script>` and runs in webbrowser instead of webserver.